# Diluted or not diluted?

Tags: meaning

So I need a little help confirming something.

This sentence:

> [...] key components of urine (urea, creatinine and uric acid) were not diluted in the fluid.

Does it mean that key components of urine *was* found in the fluid, at concentrated levels, or that the key components *was not* found in the fluid?

I think that the key components *was* found, at concentrated levels, but since english is not my first language, and in my language, this *could* be interpreted in such a way that it sounds like the key components were "watered-down".

Also, I could not find another example of use of the word "diluted" (antonym. "not diluted"), in such a way that it's causing the confusion.
I suppose it is a case of bad sentence strucuring (Something I am almost certainly guilty of when writing this question).

So which is it? Were the key components present at higher levels, or at lower levels?

Thanks.

Comment: It could be either, depending on the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having searched for that phrase and read the article (and I learned something I never knew I needed to...), I think it's used in the sense of *the key components of urine were present in the fluid, at the levels you'd expect in normal urine*. The key components hadn't been diluted in the fluid, and thus you could conclude that the fluid was urine and not urine mixed with (and therefore diluted by) some other buffering liquid.

Here's the link if anyone wants to read about [female squirting](https://vanwinkles.com/scientists-get-to-the-bottom-of-squirting-during-sex).

Comment: Me and the mrs. had an argument. Now I know I won! Thank you!